# How can I get the source code from a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get the source code of that page (using js and d3js library)
http://www.brightpointinc.com/interactive/budget/index.html?source=d3js
I want to run it localy, so i've downloaded the source of the css file and "scripts/d3.js" file and places those file in the right place. However it seems that the javascript don't want to load anyway. Is it possible to run the page localy getting the source code ? If that's the case, how should I do ?

Comment: You have also to download FederalBudget_2013_a.csv (http://www.brightpointinc.com/interactive/budget/FederalBudget_2013_a.csv) on your local machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In firefox, you can simply right-click the page and do Save As... to download the complete website including all referenced files.

I looked at the website you mention and the reason that this doesn't work for this website is because this website is not completely client-side. The javascript does server-requests, which won't work on a local copy, because of security reasons.

This results in the following error:

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
d3.js (row 1674): request.send(data == null ? null : data);
```